# already selected item should come selected at next time when I open the same page

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I have used ng-options directive in my ftl. I select an option from drop down but when next time I open the same page, earlier selected item doesn't come selected. Please solve my problem.

```
<script>
    campusApp.controller('personalDetCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("OnlineRecruitmentApplication.action?formInstruction=ngCall")
           .success(function (response) {
               $scope.categories = response;
           });
</script>
<div class="control-groups">
    <label class="control-label text-danger">Category/वर्ग </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select ng-model="appForm.category"
                ng-options="category.text for category in categories"
                ng-blur="addForm('${userApplicationId}')">
            <option value="">{{appForm.category.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean opening the same page while staying inside the app or refreshing/reopening the browser?

Comment: refreshing/reopening the browser

Comment: You will have to keep this information and send it from the server each time. Either you persist it on the server or in a cookie on client-side. Of course, it is only possible to store on server if you keep user information.

Comment: of course I have information in database but the problem is how to set that in option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data type of **appForm.category** and **category.text** for category in categories was different. Now we are using same data type at server side and default option is coming selected.